# What exactly is CDATA and what does it do?

Tags: javascript, css, cdata

I sometimes notice a CSS or JS code surrounded with `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` tags. I couldn't find any explanation to this. What does CDATA do? Why is it used by some people and what is it needed for?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577524/why-should-you-use-xml-cdata-blocks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It tells the interpreter that it should not try to interpret the data enclosed in the tags. For example, if you want a XML file to contain a comment with < or >, XML interpreters will report the file as invalid because the caracters < and > will not be part of standard tag. You simply have to surround the code with the CDATA tags.

Comment: But is it necessary for a <script> tag with Javascript? I don't see any difference in how it works or is treated.

Answer (score 8):

It marks data that shouldn't be parsed - in most cases, just HTML or text that needs to be written directly to the page.

Further explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: To be precise, data that shouldn't be parsed as XML / by the XHTML rendering engine.

Answer (score 6):

Here's some info for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

How you couldn't find anything on this is a mystery ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you write inline javascript or CSS in an HTML file (using the `script` and `style` tags), Those CDATA comments prevent things like the HTML validators from catching false positives when validating an HTML document.