# XML error at ampersand (&)

Tags: php, mysql, html, xml, database

I have a php file which prints an xml based on a MySql db.

I get an error every time at exactly the point where there is an **&** sign.

Here is some php:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$_xmlrows = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $_xmlrows .= xmlrowtemplate($row);
}

function xmlrowtemplate($dbrow){
    return "<AD>
              <CATEGORY>".$dbrow['category']."</CATEGORY>
            </AD>
}
```

The output is what I want, i.e. the file outputs the correct category, but still gives an error.

The error says: **xmlParseEntityRef: no name**

And then it points to the exact character which is a **&** sign.

This complains only if the `$dbrow['category']` is something with an **&** sign in it, for example: "**cars & trucks**", or "**computers & telephones**".

Anybody know what the problem is?

BTW: I have the encoding set to UTF-8 in all documents, as well as the xml output.

Comment: Please share more details. Also, please explain how this is related to [tag:html], [tag:mysql], or [tag:database]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`&` in XML starts an entity. As you haven't defined an entity `&WhateverIsAfterThat` an error is thrown. You should escape it with `&amp;`.

```
$string = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $string);
```

[How do I escape ampersands in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml)

To escape the other reserved characters:

```
function xmlEscape($string) {
    return str_replace(array('&', '<', '>', '\'', '"'), array('&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&apos;', '&quot;'), $string);
}
```

Comment: (Addition, but for poster) So use &amp; to properly escape it -- although instead of (dumb) string interpolation you should use something that *understands* XML (e.g. what happens when the input contains "<"?

Comment: Or, more compact, `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);`

Comment: wrapping in <![CDATA tags is the more logical solution

Comment: To be sure the string is actually safe, I think it should be done in two stages.

For example:

$string = 'Foo &amp; Bar';
$string = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $string); // Foo & Bar
$string = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $string); // Foo &amp; Bar

If there is only one stage, result can be 'Foo &amp;amp; Bar'

Comment: I would suggest you want to use the `ENT_XML1` option: `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1);` to ensure that the string is escaped appropriately for XML.

Answer (score 7):

```php
$string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1);
```

Using [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) with [`ENT_XML1`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-parameters) constant is the most universal way to solve all encoding errors (IMHO better that writing a custom function, also there are other entities to encode than `&`).

Credit: Put Wrikken's and joshweir's comment as answer to be more visible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either turn `&` into its entity `&amp;`, or wrap the contents in [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813595/what-exactly-is-cdata-and-what-does-it-do) tags.

If you choose the entity route, there are additional characters you need to turn into entities:

```
>  &gt;
<  &lt;
'  &apos;
"  &quot;
```

Background: [Beware of the ampersand when using XML](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5032714.html)

Wikipedia: [List of XML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)

Answer (score 0):

Switch and regex with using xml escape function.

```
 function XmlEscape(str) {
    if (!str || str.constructor !== String) {
        return "";
    }

    return str.replace(/[\"&><]/g, function (match) {
        switch (match) {
        case "\"":
            return "&quot;";
        case "&":
            return "&amp;";
        case "<":
            return "&lt;";
        case ">":
            return "&gt;";
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

XML uses the `&` for encoding. `&...;` are called entities. The parser takes the characters after the `&` as the name of the entity, the space is not allowed, so the parser sees an entity without a name. `&` is represented by the named entity `&amp;` itself.

The other answers show how to handle this on a string level, but you're generating XML, so using an XML library is another option.

#### XMLWriter

XMLWriter is an API to write XML sequentially. It allows the handling of large data.

```php
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri('php://stdout');
$writer->setIndent(2);
$writer->startDocument();
$writer->startElement('_');

foreach (getData() as $record) {
    $writer->startElement('AD');
    $writer->writeElement('CATEGORY', $record['category']);
    $writer->endElement();
}

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();

function getData(): array {
  return [
    ['category' => 'cars & trucks'],
    ['category' => 'computers & telephones'],
  ];
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<_>
 <AD>
  <CATEGORY>cars &amp; trucks</CATEGORY>
 </AD>
 <AD>
  <CATEGORY>computers &amp; telephones</CATEGORY>
 </AD>
</_>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function sanitize(string $data) {
    return str_replace('&', '&amp;', $data);
}
```

You are right: here is more context - the example is in relation to the ' how to deal with data containing '&' when we pass this data to SimpleXml. Of course there is also other solution to use
    `<![CDATA[some stuff]]>`

Comment: What about some more context?