# AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04

```
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

When run `sudo apt-get update` i'm just facing this issue.
Ubuntu Version: `18.04.1`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an "illegal character" in that xml (a `&` inside a string), the manual solution is to find the line (usually 265) and encode propperly the `&` as `&amp;`, the technical explanation is that a `&` inside a xml starts an entity as explanied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026522/1423096), so replacing `&` with `&amp;` makes the XML valid again.

for reference see comment by [Sun Bear](https://askubuntu.com/users/541417/sun-bear) 
 at [this askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/e-problem-executing-scripts-apt-updatepost-invoke-success-error-during-apt-ge/944156#comment1732088_1053844)

and his proposed solution here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1644498/comments/56