# What is the Point of using XML CDATA?

Tags: xml, cdata

I was reading up on XML files and came across this `<![CDATA[]]>`.

In what sort of situation would this be useful?

I understand it being used as;

> All text in an XML document will be parsed by the parser.
>
> But text inside a CDATA section will be ignored by the parser.

[from here.](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) However, It doesn't exactly go into any detail of when it may be useful and/or its relevance to xml files/etc.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) asks what does it mean, but again, not too much detail from what i can see of *what does it do* nor *when should i use it* - which is why I am asking this question now.

(i'm not exactly a pro, nor an adept - ok, more of a complete idiot actually -  even reading the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) didn't actually help, so any comprehensive answers would be great :P)

Comment: I did see that, however you obviously did not read the details of my question, as i stated the reason for it NOT being there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it to avoid XML escaping special characters.

Imagine you have an element like

`<data>...</data>`

And want to place the following text in the data element :

```
 a < b
```

Like so:

```
<data>a < b</data>
```

That doesn't work, since XML recognizes the < as a potential start of a new tag.

You can escape the < character:

```
<data>a &lt; b</data>
```

Or you can tell the XML parser to not parse your data by placing it in a CDATA section:

```
<data><![CDATA[a < b]]></data>
```

(Then again, with CDATA, your text cannot contain `]]>`)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577524/why-should-you-use-xml-cdata-blocks)

Comment: ok, so it's just like a 'global escape sequence' really? (like using /" within a string to see that the " is part of the string?

Comment: @MrCoder usig \" would rather be like the first option of escaping the < character to &lt;. CDATA is more like a raw string, where the XML parser does't look at the content to interpret it in one particular way or another.

Comment: ok, so it's almost 'ignored' and 'passed as a string' to the html. That makes more sense :) Originally, I just thought it to be a way of writing comments or something, or even ignoring completely - not that it passed the data like that. cheers for the help/patience! :)

Answer (score 1):

`<![CDATA[...]]>` is a quick and dirty way to quote text in XML.

In XML, `<`, `>`, `&` have a special meaning.  If you want to include a `<` or `>` in XML, you have to escape these as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.  But if for example you include code in XML, you might use these characters a lot and don't want to write for instance `c>='0' && c<='9'` as `c&gt;='0' &amp;&amp; c&lt;='9'`.  For these situations a more radical way has been introduced to escape text: whatever is between `<![CDATA[` and `]]&gt;` is to be interpreted verbatim.  Only the sequence `]]>` marks the end of the verbatim text.

The use of CDATA is invisible to the reader of XML.  `<this><![CDATA[a test]]></this>` represents the same element as `<this>a test</this>`.

There is one big limitation.  In a CDATA you can only represent the character available in your encoding (the `encoding="..."` in your `<?xml>` header).  If you are using an encoding like ISO-8859-1, you cannot represent characters like € or œ.

So if you write XML manually and it contains code, it is a good idea to include the whole code in CDATA to prevent problems.  So you can forget about escaping characters meaningful to XML.

But it is not a good idea to quote text programmatically with CDATA just because it is easier.  You might end up loosing some special characters and some day you might have the sequence `]]>` in your data.  It is better to escape using `&lt;` `&gt;` `&amp;` and numeric entity codes.